# why is app.get not resolving the file path in exports function

Tags: node.js, express

Still trying to understand node.js, looked up similar questions but there's  nothing that I can see for my use case.

I'm trying to get app.get from express js to work in my exports, but I'm not sure what is wrong. Is it the file path? I am rendering it in pug. but I know it's something to do with

my code:

```
    module.exports.defaultAlbumReader = function () {
  var dirArray = new Array()

  var globalFileCount = 0
  var pathArray = []

  var jsmediatags = require('jsmediatags')
  const path = require('path')
  var express = require('express')
  var app = express()

  const fs = require('fs')
  const { error } = require('console')

  app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
  // app.use('/public/Music', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
  // app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  // app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
  app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'pug');

  var filesToCount = fs.readdirSync(
    './public/Music/Pink_Floyd/WishYouWereHere/'
  )

  globalFileCount = filesToCount.length
  console.log('number of files: ' + globalFileCount)
  var songsAlbumOrder = new Array(globalFileCount)
  var index = new Array(globalFileCount)

  var files = fs.readdirSync('./public/Music/Pink_Floyd/WishYouWereHere/')

  //sort the files in order of track number ascending

  function awaitableSortingEngine (file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      jsmediatags.read('./public/Music/Pink_Floyd/WishYouWereHere/' + file, {
        onSuccess: function (tag) {
          var tags = tag.tags
          var track = tags.track
          console.log(tags.track)
          if (track.length < 4) {
            var trackNum = track.slice(0, 1)
          } else if (track.length == 4) {
            var trackNum = track.slice(0, 1)
          } else {
            var trackNum = track.slice(0, 2)
          }
          var arrayIndex = trackNum - 1
          songsAlbumOrder[arrayIndex] = file

          resolve(songsAlbumOrder)
        },
        onError: function (error) {
          console.log(':(', error.type, error.info)
          reject('error: file was rejected')
        }
      })
    })
  }

  async function getArray (files) {
    for (const file of files) {
      var data = await awaitableSortingEngine(file)
      // console.log(data)
    }

    //  setTimeout((data),1000)
    return data
  }
  async function displayData () {
    var data = await getArray(files)
    // console.log(promises.all(data))
    // data.then((arrayResult)=>{console.log(arrayResult)});
    // console.log(data)

    return data
  }

  var ordered = displayData()
  // console.log(orderedArray)
  ordered.then(result => sendToFront(result))

  function sendToFront (fileArray) {
    console.log('moooo')
    for (const file of fileArray) {
      jsmediatags.read('./public/Music/Pink_Floyd/WishYouWereHere/' + file, {
        onSuccess: function (tag) {
          var tags = tag.tags

          console.log(tags.title)
          //  console.log('made it')
          // var base64Url=Buffer.from(tags.picture.data).toString("base64");

          // var base64Url=Buffer.from(base64String).toString("base64");
          // var artInfo="data:"+tags.picture.format+";base64,"+base64Url;

          // console.log(`data:${tags.picture.format};base64,`);
          // var songRow=[tags.artist,tags.track,tags.album,tags.title,tags.year];

          app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.render('index', {
              temp: tags.artist
            })
            console.log('yayyyyyy')
          })
        },
        onError: function (error) {
          console.log(':(', error.type, error.info)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

my output:

```
number of files: 5
server started at localhost port:3000
3/5
data:image/jpeg;base64,
5/5
1/5
2/5
4/5
moooo
Welcome to the Machine
Shine On You Crazy Diamond (Parts I-V)
Have A Cigar
Wish You Were Here
Shine On You Crazy Diamond (Parts VI-IX)
done
```

The problem area is:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                res.render('index', {
                  temp: tags.artist
                })
                console.log('yayyyyyy')
              })
```

my file structure is like:

```
App
  server.js
  public
       js
         -current module.js
       music
  views
      index
```

Comment: It's not super-clear what you're trying to do, or how. Have you considered starting with a basically empty ExpressJS app and moving things piece by piece? This looks... not a lot like a typical ExpressJS app.

Comment: If nothing else it would be beneficial to break up that giant function that does many things at many layers.

Comment: I'd recommend ExpressJS's own [Getting Started docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). There's a lot going wrong here with regards to structure and app setup.

Comment: This module sorts the files into the order by track number and then I intend to display it on a table on the page....right now i'm just using temp to show that its reaching my pug template

Comment: Yes, I understand the *app's* purpose (roughly). It's the rest of it that's a bit baffling.

Comment: well my server works, I have a legitimate app that is showing my music player (which is playing music and displaying the music metadata fed from the server

Comment: it's just this export that isn't displaying on my template